# How do I install pandas datareader on windows when hit with this error?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to install pandas datareader, but I am hit with this error:

```
Collecting pandas-datareader
  Using cached pandas_datareader-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas-datareader) (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.19.0 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas-datareader) (2.28.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (2022.6)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (1.23.5)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer<3,>=2 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (2.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (3.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (1.26.13)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas-datareader) (2022.9.24)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\marcu\appdata\local\programs\python\python311\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas>=0.23->pandas-datareader) (1.16.0)
Installing collected packages: lxml, pandas-datareader
  DEPRECATION: lxml is being installed using the legacy 'setup.py install' method, because it does not have a 'pyproject.toml' and the 'wheel' package is not installed. pip 23.1 will enforce this behaviour change. A possible replacement is to enable the '--use-pep517' option. Discussion can be found at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8559
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [96 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against pre-built libxml2 andl libxslt libraries
      running install
      C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\cssselect.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\doctestcompare.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\ElementInclude.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\pyclasslookup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\sax.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\_elementpath.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\clean.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\defs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\diff.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\ElementSoup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\formfill.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\html5parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\soupparser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\usedoctest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_diffcommand.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_html5builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\_setmixin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      copying src\lxml\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\html
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron
      copying src\lxml\etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\lxml.etree_api.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml
      copying src\lxml\includes\c14n.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\config.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\dtdvalid.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etreepublic.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\htmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\relaxng.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\schematron.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\tree.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\uri.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xinclude.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlerror.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xmlschema.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xpath.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\xslt.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\etree_defs.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      copying src\lxml\includes\lxml-version.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\includes
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng\iso-schematron.rng -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\rng
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1\readme.txt -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\lxml\isoschematron\resources\xsl\iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\lxml
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -Isrc -Isrc\lxml\includes -IC:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcsrc\lxml\etree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\src\lxml\etree.obj -w
      cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/W3' with '/w'
      etree.c
      C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include\pyconfig.h(59): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'io.h': No such file or directory
      Compile failed: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      creating Users
      creating Users\marcu
      creating Users\marcu\AppData
      creating Users\marcu\AppData\Local
      creating Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp
      "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I/usr/include/libxml2 "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.32.31326\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /TcC:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit65mzfy1g.c /FoUsers\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit65mzfy1g.obj
      xmlXPathInit65mzfy1g.c
      C:\Users\marcu\AppData\Local\Temp\xmlXPathInit65mzfy1g.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      *********************************************************************************
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I am using python 3.11.0, and the command I am using to install pandas datareader is "pip install pandas-datareader" Thanks for the help!

It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.
It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there. Check the error logs carefully. You'll notice it's asking for:

```
Is libxml2 installed?
```

Try installing that with pip then retry.

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libxml2 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for libxml2

Comment: if the distribution isn't found then that's another problem. Seems like lxml is aware of the issue with 3.11. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/1977998. Try going to 3.10 and installing

Comment: @Engloosh if my answer was helpful please up vote. We’re partly here to answer for the up votes

Answer (score 0):

try:

> pip install --upgrade pip

On Windows the recommended command is:

> python -m pip install --upgrade pip